# scipy.stats: supply pdf/cdf and have scipy do the rest

Tags: python, scipy

I'd like to specify a pdf or cdf function and then have scipy build a fully functional `rv_continuous` or `rv_discrete` which I can then use to get the mean and other statistics, the other distribution function (if I gave it pdf, then give me cdf, or vice-versa), etc. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If you want a fully functional distribution, you will have to implement all of these methods yourself.

Comment: Read the docstring of `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html).  There is a section about subclassing.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser that did the trick. If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I only posted a link!  You did all the work.  Why don't you write up a solution and answer your own question?  That's perfectly acceptable on stackoverflow.